# How to count row combinations based on common value

Tags: powerbi, dax

I'm trying to find the frequency of combinations that occur per an ID value.
Example given here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZG9gJ.png

The problem is that the number of rows that could make up a combination is variable, meaning a combination could consist of just 1 value or 2, 3, 4, etc.

I'm currently trying to do this within Power BI, but perhaps another tool would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Power Query (from Power BI => Transform)

***Basic algorithm***

- Group by ID

  - for each subGroup

    - Concatenate a sorted list of Cats
    - Count the number of Cats per ID for subsequent sorting
- Then Group by COMBI

  - Aggregate with Count function

***M Code***

```
let

//change next line to however you are getting your table
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="idCat"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", Int64.Type}, {"Cat1", type text}}),

//group by ID and create COMBI 
//  and also length of each cat string for subsequen intelligent sorting
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"ID"}, {
        {"COMBI", each Text.Combine(List.Sort([Cat1])),type text},
        {"lenCat", each Text.Length(Text.Combine(List.Sort([Cat1]))),Int64.Type}
    }),
    maxLen = List.Max(#"Grouped Rows"[lenCat]),
    #"Delete length column" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Grouped Rows","lenCat"),

//Group by Cats for counting
    #"Grouped Cats" = Table.Group(#"Delete length column",{"COMBI"},{
        {"COUNT", each List.Count([COMBI]), Int64.Type}
    }),
    #"Pad COMBI for Sorting" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Grouped Cats",{"COMBI", each Text.PadStart(_,maxLen), type text}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Pad COMBI for Sorting",{{"COMBI", Order.Ascending}}),

    #"Trim Leading Spaces" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Sorted Rows",{"COMBI", each Text.Trim(_), type text})
in
    #"Trim Leading Spaces"
```

[image]